# LED lamps glow with switch off

Tags: led, light

My stairway LED ceiling lamps on 3-way switches glow next morning after being off all night. Is this an indication of stray voltage, bad switch or short circuit? They still glow today after 14 hours.

Comment: How long do they continue to glow for? do they ever die out?

Comment: Today they still glow after 14 hours

Comment: do you have illuminated switches? you can replace the bulbs with newer/better bulbs, which should have a bleeder resistor that prevents low-level illumination.